# Resolution calculus converting into set of clauses

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Here is $T$:

> - $a \lor \neg b$
> - $\neg a \lor (c \land d)$
> - $b$

I am suppose to use **resolution calculus** to prove that $T \models d \land b$ holds.

As in the first step, we translate $T$ into a *set of clauses*, all clauses being in **CNF**.

My lecturer converts $T$ into the following clauses:

> **Clause 1**: $\neg a \lor \neg b$
>
> **Clause 2**: $a \lor c$
>
> **Clause 3**: $a \lor d$
>
> **Clause 4**: $b$

**Clause 1** and **clause 4** seem correct to me (in **CNF**).

But howcome $\neg a \lor (c \land d)$ in $T$ becomes into **Clause 2 & 3** ($a \lor c$, $a \lor d$)?

Shouldn't it be $(a \land c) \lor (a \land d)$ (distribution law)?

Comment: Your professor is correct in applying the distributive law.  Secondly there is an error in Clause 1 and what you have written earlier (the 'not' sign before $a$ is missing.

Comment: @Shailesh - wy do you think that $¬a \lor (c \land d)$ is equivalent to $(a \lor c) \land (a \lor d)$ ? see [Distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Comment: The distribution is: $\quad\large\color{red}{\neg a~\vee~}(c\color{blue}{~\wedge~}d) \;\dashv\vdash\; (\color{red}{\neg a~\vee~}c)\color{blue}{~\wedge~} (\color{red}{\neg a~\vee~}d)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp ok i see that I interpretated the distrubution law wrong, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having corrected the wrong application of the distribution law, we have the following [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)):

**Clause 1**: $a ∨ ¬b$

**Clause 2**: $\lnot a ∨ c$

**Clause 3**: $\lnot a ∨ d$

**Clause 4**: $b$

and the negation of the formula to be proved:

5) $\lnot d \lor \lnot b$.

Now we have to apply [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)), starting with 4)-1) and 4)-5) deriving:

6) $a$

7) $\lnot d$.

Then we have to use 7)-3) to derive:

8) $\lnot a$.

Finally, using 6) and 8) we conclude with the *empty clause*: $\bot$.